# How to input a number in base 36?

Tags: c++

How can I do this?

```
int number;
cin >> number;
```

I want numbers to be entered in base 36 ( They are entered in base 36 by assumption ). In base 36 A means 10, B means 11, C 12 and so on. How can C++ understand that 'A' is not a character but a number in base 36 and would 'cin >>' work for this purpose?

Answer (score 6):

You need to write a wrapper class that holds an `int&`, and overload `>>` for that class such that it parses in base36. The usage would look like this:

```
int i;
cin >> base36(i);
// or if you do it more generically:
cin >> base(36, i);
```

Standard C++ doesn't provide I/O for bases other than 8, 10 and 16.

Comment: I can't use classes and Object-Oriented Programming features in writing this program... only control statements are allowed..

Comment: @M.HosainMa'refat: `cin >> number` is using classes and OOP features. You're out of luck, I'm afraid!

Comment: @M.Hosain Ma'refat it's impossible when using C++. Why are you using it?

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit C-ish but you could input a plain string and then convert it to an integer using [`strtol(l)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) with a base argument of 36.

> The set of valid digits for base-2 integer is 01, for base-3 integer
>   is 012, and so on. For bases larger than 10, valid digits include
>   alphabetic characters, starting from Aa for base-11 integer, to **Zz for
>   base-36 integer**. The case of the characters is ignored. In non-default
>   locales, additional numeric formats may be accepted.

As Jesse Good points out in the comments, in C++11 there's also [`std::stol(l)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) which also calls `std::strtol` but throws exceptions when the conversion can't be performed.

Comment: Don't forget about [std::stol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks, I remember I saw `std::stoi` and friends but forgot about them.

Comment: Assume I input ‫‪' L.1 ' . Should I define a string as the value of input (string number; cin >> number ) and then use stol( number )? then L.1 will be intercepted as 21.1 (base 10) ?

Comment: @M.HosainMa'refat Are you trying to read real-values ? I thought you meant integer values in base 36 ?

Comment: I'm trying to read inputs from keyboard.. both integers and real-values ... (by assumption , inputs are entered in base 36)